# Xcode couldn't be found at /Applications/Xcode.app

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I get Xcode couldn't be found at /Applications/Xcode.app when I try to run the sample single view app from Visual Studio 2019.

Do I have to install XCode on the windows machine I am using or the Mac that is building the code?

I don't have visual studio on the Mac and was hoping that I wouldn't have to install it. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to install VS and XCode on the Mac.  This is clearly covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/?pivots=windows)

1. Set up Windows (Install Visual Studio 2019)
2. Set up Mac (**Install Xcode and Visual Studio for Mac**)
3. Pair to Mac (Connect Visual Studio 2019 to the Mac)

Comment: Adding a comment Jason made today elsewhere: *"Then [edited] launch XCode on the Mac. Often it needs to install additional code but only prompts to do that when its launched"*